# How to hit post request in javascript , which hit server side swift server?

Tags: javascript, swift, perfect, server-side-swift

How to hit post request in javascript, which hit server side server(Perfect) ?

I got all my parameters in function in script tag . Now I am facing difficulties to hit post request from function to Server

Comment: I believe you are not talking about the Swift programming language. Why did you tag Swift?

Comment: well , I am making project in server side swift (same as Php) and it is my first project thats way I write swift here.

Comment: Then please don't tag [tag:swift], the tag [tag:Swift] is for the progeamming language for iOS, macOS and Linux, not [tag:perfect]

Comment: look this http://perfect.org

Answer (score 1):

- with jquery (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- plain js (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)